# Please explain the difference

Tags: grammar, difference

Please explain the difference

1) I Hadn't been doing the Task since 29th April 
2) I haven't been doing the task since 29th April

As I understand an exact time cannot be used with Present Perfect?

Comment: "As I understand an exact time cannot be used with Present Perfect?" - that's actually not quite true, depending on whether you consider *since April 29th* an "exact time" or not.

Comment: Oh okk, so which sentence makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exact date can be used with Present perfect:

> I have been working here since May 15th.

I can't think of a context where I would use either of your sentences, so I'll try and explain the difference between both verbal structures. This is **tense sequencing**:

> I **have been doing** this for 3 hours, I'm exhausted.
>
> I **had been doing** this for 3 hours **when** my mom walked in.

In the **first case**, we're in the present: the speaker has started doing something 3 hours ago, and is still doing it. Hence, he's exhausted.

In the **second case**, we're telling a story in the past: the speaker had started to do something a few hours earlier, then his mom walked in.

What did you want to say in your sentence exactly ?

### Edit

The only context where I can see your second sentence is in a discussion such as:

> **Have you been doing** this task since April 28th ?
>
> No, I **haven't been doing** this task since April 28th, I **have only been doing** it since May 03rd.

But it is still very weird.

Comment: I want to say that I was not able to do the task since April 29th

Comment: This page says we cannot use exact time with present perfect http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html

Comment: @user3608985 This is not quite true. The actual rule is that the present perfect is a present tense, so you cannot use the PrPf with a time expression which **does not include the present**, But the preposition *since*, when used with the present perfect defines a timeSPAN which runs from the named time **up to** the present, so that's OK.

Comment: @user3608985, the rule means you can't say something like "I haven't done it on April 28th." You can say "I haven't done it **since** April 28th". That's not an exact time, it's a timeSPAN, as StoneyB says.